# MySQL ORDER BY statement and PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I am loosing my mind I can't figure this out please help.

Here is my sql :

```
$query = " select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from programme where 1=1    ".$_SESSION['subject_where']." ".$_SESSION['practice_where']." ".$_SESSION['key_stage_where']." ".$_SESSION['targeted_group_where']." ".$_SESSION['search_where']." " ORDER BY Rating DESC " ";`
```

My MySQL select works fine but I want to order my search results by ratings.  When I insert `ORDER BY Rating DESC` after the variables I always get the following error:

```
Error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home4/kenobi/public_html/programmes.php on line 23
```

Please help - What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You ought to get a good text editor with syntax highlighting. When I edited it above to activate the highlighting, you can see that there's  an errant `"` right before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: That section should look like `$_SESSION['search_where']." ORDER BY Rating DESC ";`

Comment: How could I be so blind...too many quotes :) Thank you so so much! it worked!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = " select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from programme where 1=1 ".$_SESSION['subject_where']." ".$_SESSION['practice_where']." ".$_SESSION['key_stage_where']." ".$_SESSION['targeted_group_where']." ".$_SESSION['search_where']." ORDER BY Rating DESC ";
```

You have those extra quotes in there. Aside that though... 1 = 1 huh? Is this just for testing?